# Problems signing in with Facebook on some phones

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have gotten reports from some people that they cannot log into my app with Facebook. Most of the reports come from users with Samsung phones. I have asked them to reinstall both my app and the Facebook app, and try with and without the Facebook app installed but that does not seem to help. My app is using Single-Sign-On.

I have tested with multiple Samsung phones and I have never been able to reproduce this problem. Does anyone know how this could be solved?

Comment: When you say tested on multiple Samsung handsets, do you mean through Eclipse or did you test with a signed APK?

Comment: what problem you are facing like facebook screen not open or there is any sign in error

Comment: @SiddharthLele Tested with the signed and live application. I have a lot of users with Samsung phones and its only for a very small percent that it is not working.

Comment: @Rishabh.CreatioSoft The reports just says that it is not working, and I can't see that they even have tried to connect.

Comment: @Heinrisch: I wanted to check if you had not in fact tested the signed APK. I had a similar problem with my app. But that was global in nature. That is, not limited to a specific brand. Turned out, I had not generated the Hash Key with my signing key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that the user had "Don't keep activities" under "Developer options" checked. This basically kills the app that tries to auth when the auth dialog is launched.